# rails image path in background-image in css

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image at `assets/images/folder/image.png`.

How do I declare the url in bacground-image in css in order to get to that image?

I tried

```
url(..images/folder/image.png)

url(/assets/images/image.png)
```

and other options. Non worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non worked. I managed to do it with:

```
background-image: url('folder/image.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
background-image: asset-url('folder/image.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

File extension: `steles.css.erb`

Path: `background: url(<%= asset_path('image.jpg') %>);`